# Compressing data traffic over a network

Tags: networking, compression, http-compression

I am looking for a distinction or what is needed for data compression over a network.

Now i am not talking about something simple like http/and image compression, but am looking for something more efficient and that actually compresses the network data.

It could be something that compresses at point A and decompresses at Point B with some device, or computer.

But does something like this exist or what would be the distinction I am looking for to tackle something like this?

Is there anything that can split up the information and compress it on the way to save traffic? And I am talking about serious compression here of all data.

Comment: Most data going over the network is already compressed.  So you won't get much, if any gain.  You might in fact get a tiny amount of expansion instead.  In general the data should be compressed at the server/client level where you might know something about the data that would help you apply the right compression approach, or know that it's already compressed.

Answer (score 1):

For Headers, ROHC can be used. It is a method to compresses the headers like TCP, IP, UDP, RTP of Internet packets.

It compresses the IPv4 or IPv6 headers overhead of 40 bytes or 60 bytes to 1 or 2 bytes.

Refer to RFC3095 for RTP, UDP and ESP. 
Refer to RFC4996 for TCP/IP

For compression of data, any of the normal data compression algorithm can be used.

Answer (score 0):

For point to point compression you have applications like:

[Zebedee](http://www.winton.org.uk/zebedee/) or [IPTunnelManager](http://www.apbsoft.com/products/iptunnelmng/features.html)

Once I did a java implementation with zlib compression to access database over a slow VPN connection, it improve the response times by a factor of 3.

Keep in mind that when you use a `tunnel` you have to connect to your end of the tunnel and not to the original destination, this works well if you have only one destination that you want to reach, otherwise you need to use different ports/tunnels or a protocol to communicate which endpoint you want to reach.

Answer (score 0):

You can try many compress algorithms such as [gzip](http://www.gzip.org/), [lzo](http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/), [quicklz](http://www.quicklz.com/manual.html), [lz4](https://code.google.com/p/lz4/), [snappy](https://code.google.com/p/snappy/) and so on.